# How can I type values ​of an argument using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I recently started to study typescript and I've been having a hard time doing some typing. I recently created a Vue project with Typescript and had the following problem:

```
Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This is my code:

```
type usersTypes = {
  phone: number,
  age: number
}

const usersTest = computed(() => {
  const users: usersTypes = {
    phone: 99999999,
    age: 20
  }

  return users
})
const filtered = 'test'

function getUsers(data){  //Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  console.log('data: ', data)
  console.log('users phone: ', data.users.phone) // Unsafe member access .users on an `any` value.
  console.log('filter: ', data.filter) // Unsafe member access .filter on an `any` value.
  
}

onMounted(() => {
  getUsers({
    users: usersTest.value,
    filter: filtered
  })
})
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mxY8KW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  You should either define `computed()` and `onMonunted()` or remove them from the example.

Comment: Does the question depend on vue?  If so you should probably tag it as such.  If not you should probably remove the dependence on vue from the example and question text.

Comment: Sorry, I already edited my question and tagged Vue.

Comment: The issue stems from you not declaring a type for `data` in your `getUsers()` function.  While *we* can see that your passing in an object that contains a `usersTypes` and something else, Typescript has no way of knowing that.  Typescript, for lack of a better term, does its type checks at compile time, not run time.  It sees a function with a single, untyped parameter and casts it as an `any` type because you haven't told it otherwise.  One way around this would be to create a class that has a `usersTypes` and whatever `filter` is as members, and then `function getUsers(data: className) {}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Let me get this straight, should I create a class that takes 'usersTypes'?  [codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-iz20yr?file=/index.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Making this an answer because providing code examples in comments is difficult.  The way I'd do it is:

```
class User {
   phone: number;
   age: number;

   constructor(phone: number, age: number) {
      this.phone = phone;
      this.age = age;
   }
}

class UserData {
   user: User; // remember: classes create types
   filter: string; // don't know what you're actually using for your filter member, so use the right type here

   constructor(user: User, filter: string) {
      this.user = user;
      this filter = filter;
   }
}

let testUser = new User(123456, 20);
let data = new UserData(testUser, "age");

function dataTest(testData: UserData) {
   console.log("Data:", testData);
   console.log("Phone:", testData.user.phone);
   console.log("Filter:", testData.filter);
}

dataTest(data);
```

Keep in mind that this is just one approach.  The important thing to remember is to mind your types and explicitly declare them

Comment: Just to be clear, you *can* do something similar with type aliases, but I personally lean towards classes and objects because it allows one to do things with their internal state while keeping encapsulation and type safety